# Proof $f\in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm supposed to show $f\in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$ in a proof. Here, we're dealing with a compact linear injective operator $A:X\rightarrow Y$, where both $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces. Furthermore, $A$ has dense range, i.e., $\overline{A(X)}=Y$. In the proof it is assumed $f\not\in V:=\{A\varphi\ |\ \varphi\in X,\ ||\varphi||\leq\rho\}$ for some $\rho>0$.

I have constructed the following argument:

From the information of $A$ we know the adjoint operator $A^{*}$ will be linear and injective. Therefore $N(A^{*})=\{0\}$, since for linear operators being injective means $A^{*}g=0\Rightarrow g=0$.

Since it is assumed $f\not\in V$ that implies $f\neq 0$ and therefore $f\perp N(A^{*})$, i.e., $f\in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$.

Does this make sense or do I have some mistakes/lack of arguments that $f\in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $A^*$ is injective ?

Comment: @S.Cho Because $A$ has dense range.

Comment: Okey, but if $N(A^*)=\{0\}$, then $N(A^{*})^{\perp}=Y$. Following what you wrote you get $f\in Y$. I think this is not important.

Comment: @S.Cho The whole idea is for me to argue $f\in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$ since that implies $f\in\overline{A(X)}$ and that allows me to use a theorem to show something has a solution.

Comment: What is the information on $f$, if it is just an element of $Y$ the result is obvious, since $Y=N(A^{*})^{\perp}$. If not, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: The only information on $f$ is that it is not in $V$.

Comment: I guess that $f\in Y$. Are you working on Tikhonov regularisation ?

Comment: Yes, Tikhonov regularization and quasi-solutions.

Comment: Do you want to prove that if $Au=f$ has a solution, then a necessary condition is $f \in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$ ? If not, you can edit your post and clarify what result you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to show.

Comment: Okey, I will add an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to prove the following result: Consider the operator equation $$Au=f, u\in X, \; f\in Y, (1).$$
Then, a necessary condition for existence of a solution $u$ to  $(1)$ is $f \in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$.

Assume that $(1)$ has a solution $u$. Let $v\in N(A^{*})$, we have $$(f,v)_Y=(Au, v)_Y=(u, A^* v)_Y=0,$$
Then, $f\perp v$ for all $v \in N(A^{*})$, which implies that $f \in N(A^{*})^{\perp}$.

PS: This result not require injectivity or dense range assumptions.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Since $N(A^{*})=\{0\}$ its orthogonal complement is the entire space $Y$. So any vector $f$ belongs to it. I don't what you mean when you say ' $f\neq 0$ and therefore $f\perp (N(A^{*})$'. There is really nothing to prove here once you know that $N(A^{*})=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can see what you mean, I think I just made it more complicated than it needed to be. But is my way of arguing $N(A^{*})=\{0\}$ valid?

Comment: @James Yes, it is valid. The fact that range of $A$ is dense implies that kernel of $A^{*}$ is $\{0\}$.